# Statistic for a set intersect

Tags: mathematical-statistics, group-differences

I have two set $A$ and $B$ with $C = A \cap B$. Given are the sizes (finite) $|A|,|B|$ but not $|C|$.
I have random sample from $A \cup B$ where for every $x \in A \cup B$ I know whether is in $A, B$ solely or in $C$.

I want to understand the size of $C$ from the sample.

- What are the assumption I need on $A,B,C$?
- Is there a "known" statistic for that kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $N_A$ be # of A solely, $N_B$ be # of B solely and $N_C$ be the # of both A and B. Define $n_.$ as observed corresponding #s from the sample. $N_A + N_C = |A|$ and $N_B+N_C=|B|$ are known constant. And question is to estimate $N_C$.

At first, need to check if $\frac{n_A+n_C}{N_A+N_C}$ and $\frac{n_B+n_C}{N_B+N_C}$
are close. If close, it is OK. Otherwise, maybe your sample is not random sample.

Given your sample is random sample, calculate the ratio of

$r_C = \frac {n_C}{(n_A+n_C) + (n_B+n_C)}$

This ratio from the sample can be treated as the estimate of the same ratio in the population.

Next, $N_C$ can be estimated by

$\hat{N_C} = r_C\{(N_A + N_C)+(N_B+N_C)\}=r_C(|A|+|B|)$

I am not 100% sure it is correct answer.

Comment: 1. why would would I use n_c twice in the denominator of r_c
2. How can I define statistical measure for this like a CI? 
3. How would I test if this is an unbiased estimator?

Comment: 1. Because $N_c$ appears in $|A|$ and $|B|$. 2: Not easy, maybe you can try bootstrapping. 3: Need to prove that $E(\hat N_C) = N_C$ mathematically. It may be hard. You can try the simulation if you like.